# Perl/MySQL Relationship Query

Tags: mysql, sql, perl, relationship

I have the following perl code that will eventually be a webpage:

```
my($dbh) = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=dbsrv;database=database","my_sqlu","my_sqlp") or die "Canny Connect";
my($sql) = "SELECT * FROM hardware where srv_name = \"$srv_name\"";
my($sth) = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$sth->bind_col( 1, \my($db_id));
$sth->bind_col( 2, \my($db_srv_name));
$sth->bind_col( 5, \my($db_site));
$sth->fetchrow();
$sth->finish ();
my($sql) = "SELECT sites.\`site_code\`, sites.\`long_name\` FROM \`hardware\` JOIN \`sites\` ON \`sites\`.id=\`hardware\`.\`site\` where \`hardware\`.\`id\`=\'$db_id\'";
my($sth) = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$sth->bind_col( 1, \my($db_site_code));
$sth->bind_col( 2, \my($db_long_name));
$sth->fetchrow();
$sth->finish ();
$dbh->disconnect;
print "$db_site_code<br>$db_long_name";
```

The query above does work however what I'm trying to find out is there any way I can run one SQL query and get the db_site_code and db_long_name from the sites DB without running the 2nd query? The hardware DB has the foreign key 'id' in the sites Db.

When you read anything about relational DBs they all say it's by far the most efficient method of getting data from your database but I just can't see how this is any quicker than just running 2 select queries. What I've done above would surely take longer than `"select from hardware where srv_name = $srv_name"` then `"select from sites where id = db_site_id"`? Any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before you cause yourself serious harm, please take the small amount of time necessary to use [proper SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/perl) in your application.

Comment: Thanks tadman. I will do. It's only for a local intranet but I agree there are some evil people out there and some of them might work with me!

Comment: The code you run on your intranet could become code you run publicly at any time.  Use best security habits at all times.

Comment: Also, the users who seem most simple often find the weirdest ways to get data they usually shouldn't get, or to create shortcuts to be 'more efficient' by tricking your web app.

Comment: Anyone named "O'Malley" will really appreciate it if you properly escape all your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do this with placeholders as well as a combined query. If I understand your DB correctly, you can just omit the first query and add the server name instead of the ID in the second query. I might be mistaken there, but my example will still be of value for the Perl suggestions.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# Create DB connection
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:host=dbsrv;database=database","my_sqlu","my_sqlp")
  or die "Cannot connect to database";
# Create the statement handle
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(<<'SQLQUERY') or die $dbh->errstr;
  SELECT s.site_code, s.long_name 
  FROM hardware h 
  JOIN sites s ON s.id=h.site 
  WHERE h.srv_name=?
SQLQUERY
$sth->execute('Server Name'); # There's the parameter
my $res = $sth->fetchrow_hashref; # $res now has a hash ref with the first row

print "$res->{'site_code'}<br>$res->{'long_name'}";
```

There were a few issues with your code I'd like to point out to you:

- You should **always** `use strict` and `use warnings`. They make your life easier!
- You can leave the parens `(` and `)` out with `my`. Saves you keystrokes and makes your code more readable.
- You can (*but do not have to*, this is preference!) leave out the parens after method calls that do not have arguments. Decide this for yourself.
- As was already pointed out, always use [placeholders](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#Placeholders-and-Bind-Values) with DBI. They are very simple. Now you don't have to escape the `"` with backslashes. Instead, just use `?`.
- Once you've combined your query, you can put it in a heredoc (`<<'SQLQUERY'`). It's a string that lasts from the next line to the delimiter (`SQLQUERY`). That way, your query is easier to read.
- You can use one of the ref-`fetchrow`-methods to get all your result's columns into one hash. I used [`$sth->fetchrow_hashref`](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/DBI.pm#fetchrow_hashref) because I find it most convenient. You've got the complete row and all the columns are named hash keys.
- If called in a small scope (like a short `sub`), you don't need to `finish` a statement handle. It will be finished and destroyed by Perl automatically once it goes out of scope.

---

Another thing about performance: If this is just run occasionally, don't worry about it. You can profile your queries with [DBI::Profile](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.622/lib/DBI/Profile.pm) to see which way it is faster, but you should only do that if you really need to.

In my experience, especially with very huge queries and a very busy database, two or three queries are a lot better than a single big one because they do not take over the servers resources. But again, that is something you need to profile and benchmark (if the need arises).

Comment: Many thanks simbabque. Very good advice and it has given me a lot to think about! Your example did exactly what I was looking for. Luckily for me I've just created the Db and this was the first SQL for this project so it's not much effort required to change my scripts/techniques.

Comment: @NuttyP you're welcome. =) Don't hesitate to ask more questions, and always show code!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from @tadman's recommendation to use placeholders, I'd tag this as a sql question as well, but your solution is to simply add

> srv_name = \"$srv_name\"

to your second where clause, so that your statement is:

```
"SELECT sites.\`site_code\`, sites.\`long_name\` FROM \`hardware\` JOIN \`sites\` ON \`sites\`.id=\`hardware\`.\`site\` where \`hardware\`.\`id\`=\'$db_id\'";
```

I strongly second @tadman's suggestion though -- use prepared statements and/or placeholders whenever possible.

Comment: So surely I'm just as quick then to 'select from sites where id = $db_site' rather than doing a JOIN? I also have about 30 values I'll get from hardware table that I haven't included in my code above but only need long_name and site_code from sites table.